# how to deal with access token and refresh token in client side

Tags: security, browser, access-token, restful-authentication

I am creating a website using AngularJS client side and communicating in REST with a backend (in an other domain).

To authenticate every calls, I pass a token through the header of each HTTPS call : "Authorization : Bearer access_tokenXXXXXX"

When the token expires, I am able to create a new one thanks to a refresh_token.

The access_token and the refresh_token need to be stored client side, because the browser needs to have it in clear text before setting it in the HTTP request header.

My questions are :

**Question 1** : What is the recommanded way to store the access_token and the refresh_token to make it available to the browser so it is relatively secure? (I have quiet sensitive data like personal pictures)

**Question 2** : What are the recommanded lifetime (= time before it is not usable) for access_token AND refresh_token? (FYI I refresh the token after a 401 response, and my app is a social app)

**Question 3** : Do I have an architactural issue? Should I change it in order not to have JavaScript using token at all, and use HTTP-ONLY cookies?

Thanks :)

Geoffrey

UPDATE :

I finally chosed to go for HTTP-ONLY cookies. I am using Django Oauth Toolkit so Django is waiting the authorization in the HTTP header, and not in a cookie.

To solve that, I am using a Middleware that gather the token of the cookie and set it in the header. It should also allow me to re-authenticate the user (with the refresh token) before the access_token expires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're right in asking question 3. Definitely use HTTP-Only cookies, that's the safest type of browser storage.

As described in the links provided by smwikipedia, using HTTP-Only cookies helps defend against XSS. To also defend against CSRF you should check out [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection) AngularJS mechanism.

The actual format of the cookies can be JWT or anything else.

The answer to question 2 really depends on your users' sweet spot in trading off between tight security and convenience. You know your users best so it's really your own judgement call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will switching to HTTP-ONLY cookies. concerning CSRF, I am using Django Rest Framework with this module : https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers and it is working perfectly, so I should be OK :)

Comment: I assume that you mean HTTPS-Only instead of HTTP-Only ?

Comment: HTTP-Only is a flag set on the cookies which tells the browser not to give JavaScript access to it, another flag - "SECURE" tells the browser not to send the cookies without using HTTPS. So you need should use both flags on authentication related cookies

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar questions to yours.

I am developing a service layer for both `browser-based` and `non-browser` clients. I plan to use JWT (JSON Web Token) to authenticate both.

It's too long for a comment so I post it as an answer.

For question 1, according to [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/), they recommend to store JWT token in cookie due to security considerations.

For question 2, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration) is a thread about expiration handling for JWT.

For question 3, I have no comment yet.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I will go for HTTP-ONLY secured cookies :) (but I won't implement JWT, it seems overkill)