# Logout Session Expiration with Angularjs and Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, jwt

I built my APIs with laravel 5, both my web application and mobile app use the same APIs.  On the web app there is a default expiration of 60 minutes after which user will have to log back in again.  However on mobile i do not want that, no automatic session expiration for mobile, the user can only be logged out after they have clicked the logout button on the app.

I use JWT with satellizer for my authentication, i would like to know how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you use oAuth 2.0?

Comment: Does you API provide JWT tokens?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup as you have on my web application and mobile app.
I simply store the username/email and password on the phone (native) and everytime the user opens the app it does a call to receive a new JWT. 
When the user is loggin out on the phone, the password is removed.

I think this is the simplest solution, and for security you can encrypt the password in the storage.

Comment: I will try this out, it seems simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the current practice based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration) is that you prolong or refresh the token before it expires. I do not believe you can't *not* have an expiration.