# Strongloop - How to re-generate token after some days?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using strongloop to make mobile APIs. In Stongloop accessToken expires after 14 days.

So the scenario is like below:

> Day 1

1. User login & get AccessToken
2. Using this accessToken request for Other APIs(like get all users list)

> Day 15 (accessToken is expired)

1. Using accessToken got on **Day 1** request for API - get all users list

On day 15 it will respond with access deny.. because access token is expired..

I want to make such API that if user open App On Day 1 & then Day 15. it should be logged In automatically. with new accessToken.

In short: I want to make such mechanism that if accessToken is expired It should re-generate accessToken & provide in response.

Other suggestion to make workflow like mine?

Comment: HI, the usual approach is to implement a refresh token with longer expiration time and use this token to get a new one, other possibility would be to just make the token valid for longer time if it's ok for your business case. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration

Comment: You can use <host>/api/AccessTokens/create method. Use sample payload as following {
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "01-09-2016",
  "userId": "57c7b04f8a424c9023dfdd"
}

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?