# How can I reset the JWT token expiration time?

Tags: java, jwt

I have created a JWT token along with expiration time for authentication purpose.
Each time
when a url hits in the application i am checking for the token. I want to increase the JWT token expiration time. The following is how i done. but the token is expiring by taking the expiration time which is already set while creating the token.

```
//creating JWT token only once when user logged in

String jwtToken = new String(Jwts.builder().setSubject(user.getUserId())
                    .setExpiration(expTime).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact());

// checking the presence of token every time

Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey")
                            .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken).getBody();

claims.setExpiration(time); // trying to reset the expiration time
```

I don't know what's going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the expiration time is part of the token itself and it's not possible to extend the expiration time of a token without a new one.

Please refer to [JWT (JSON Web Token) automatic prolongation of expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration) for more discussion about this.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to recreate the token.  All the information in the token is signed, making the token unique depending on the values in the token.  Changing the claim that you pull from the token doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

//try it once

**int expTime=System.currentTimeMillis()+86400000;**

// 1 day = 86400000(in millisecond)

// ** we need to convert expiration time in millisecond because setExpiration() method accept expiration time in millisecond**

Answer (score -1):

It seems `expTime` defined in the previous code lines.

ex:- You can change this value.

```
int expTime = 43200000 //after 12 hours(Should in ms)
```

I think the best practice is to set this in the property file as follows. Then you can change that time after building the project.

```
app.expTime=43200000
```

After that call this value from token provide file

```
@Value("${app.expTime}")
private int expTime;
```