# JWT Token authentication, expired tokens still working, .net core Web Api

Tags: authentication, token, jwt, .net-core

I'm building a .net core web api.

Preface - I've implemented token authentication as per https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core and https://dev.to/samueleresca/developing-token-authentication-using-aspnet-core. I've also read a few issues on github and here on SO.

This also came in handy https://goblincoding.com/2016/07/24/asp-net-core-policy-based-authorisation-using-json-web-tokens/.

After implementing it all I'm feeling like I'm missing something.

I've created a simple Angular application that sits in a web client. When I authenticate, client is sent a token. I'm storing that in session for now (still in dev so will address security concerns around where to store it later).

Not really sure this ([JWT (JSON Web Token) automatic prolongation of expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration)) is useful as I haven't implemented refresh tokens as far as I can see.

I noticed that when I call logout, and then log back in again, the client is sent a new token - as expected. However, if the token expiry time is passed (I set it to 1 minute for testing) and then the page is refreshed, the token seems to remain the same in my app. **i.e. it's as if the token never expires?!**

**I would have expected the client to be returned a 401 Unauthorised error and I can then handle forcing the user to re-authenticate.**

**Is this not how this should work?** Is there some auto-refresh token magic going on in the background that is default (I haven't set up any notion of refresh tokens in the tutorials explicitly)? Or am I missing something about the concept of token auth?

Also - **if this is a perpetually refreshing token, should I be concerned about security if the token was ever compromised?**

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I believe this has to do with ClockSkew in JwtBearerOptions.

Change to TimeSpan.Zero as I think the default is set to 5 minutes (not 100% sure though).

I have posted some sample code below that is to be placed in Startup.cs => Configure.

```cs
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Jwt",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            }
        });
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153080/clock-skew-and-tokens about clock-skew

Answer (score 28):

If your expiry time is well over the default (5 mins) or over a set a time like I had and it still considers expired token as valid, and setting the `ClockSkew` to `TimeSpan.Zero` has no effect, make sure you have the property

```
ValidateLifetime
```

set to `true` as I had mine set to `false` causing the problem, which totally make sense, but it was an easy oversight.

```
services.AddAuthentication(option =>
    {
        option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtToken:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtToken:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
               Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtToken:SecretKey"]))
        };
    });
```

Comment: For me, I needed both ValidateLifetime AND ClockSkew using Core 2.2

Comment: I can confirm that this works in NetCore3.1. Funny that this is not really documented in the docu: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.clockskew?view=azure-dotnet. The default is 5 minutes (Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.defaultclockskew?view=azure-dotnet).

Answer (score 18):

There is an additional delay of 5 minutes in the library itself.

If you are setting 1 minute as indicated for expiration, the total will be 6 minutes. If you set 1 hour the total will be 1 hour and 5 minutes.

Comment: what do you mean with *additional delay of 5 minutes in the library itself*? Do you mean additional to the already mentioned `ClockSkew`?

Comment: He means the already mentioned `ClockSkew` I would say.

Comment: Maybe, but there's already a good and clear answer about the ClockSkew, so why do we need an additonal, quite unclear answer?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about ClockSkew, it was a way that I found to exemplify.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.defaultclockskew?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added a new SecurityTokenDescriptor which contains properties that take the current date and time and expires based on our requirements.
Below is a sample login controller with a post request, which in turn returns the user details with a token.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserWithToken>> Login([FromBody] User user)
        {
             user = await _context.Users
                                    .Include(u => u.Reservations)
                                .Where(u => u.Email == user.Email
                                   && u.Password == user.Password)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            UserWithToken userWithToken = new UserWithToken(user);

            if (userWithToken == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtsettings.SecretKey);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email)
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            userWithToken.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return userWithToken;
        }
```

Here token will expires in 10 minutes.