.NET8 ASP.NET Core Web API : JWT error : Bearer error="invalid_token"
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project where I have to use JWT tokens. But I'm facing an error - no matter what I do. I'm able to generate tokens upon signin, but when I'm trying to use the generated token to call my weather controller, I get an error

Bearer error="invalid_token - 401 unauthorized

I have searched everywhere, tried my best to understand what's the issue..
This is my controller where I'm generating the tokens:
Initially Generated JWT
Postman error upon HttpGet Request
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
     [HttpPost("login")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> signIn(UserCred userDetails)
     {
         if (userDetails != null && userDetails.PhoneNumber != null && userDetails.Pin!= null)
         {
             UserDetails user = _user.GetUser(userDetails.PhoneNumber, userDetails.Pin);

             if (user != null)
             {
                 var claims = new[] 
                              {
                                  new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _config["Jwt:Subject"]),
                                  new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                                  new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                                  new Claim("UserId", user.Id),
                                  new Claim("DisplayName", user.FirstName),
                                  new Claim("UserName", user.LastName),
                                  new Claim("Email", user.Email)
                              };

                 var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
                 var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                 var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                                      _config["Jwt:Audience"],
                                      claims,
                                      expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                                      signingCredentials: signIn);

                 return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
             }
             else
             {
                  return BadRequest("Invalid credentials");
             }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}   

And here is program.cs for reference:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_specificOrigin";
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins, policy =>
    {
        policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")

));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

the Generated Token Works fine when I test on JWT debugger websites but dosent work on my API
JWT Debugger Result
I'm really stuck here. Let me share the project's github repo, for reference: TechBuzzersBank API
I think the error is somewhere in my controller, but I'm unable to fix it. Maybe it's with the way I'm calling the API (in postman)?

Show us the other endpoints that you’re trying to call after sign in.

@Alex repository is provided, you can check it out there

im trying to call WeatherController( the default API ) ive added [Authorize] annotation to test if the JWT is working.. But unfortunately, it isn't

I would suggest you remove your database credentials from the public repository you linked... Have a look at adding a .gitignore as well so you don't push your binaries and local configuration.

@P.Magnusson , Ops. I DIdn't notice, ill remove that ASAP. please let me know if you find the fix

Try to set ClockSkew = Timespan.Zero in your TokenValidationParameters(). See this link for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153080/clock-skew-and-tokens.

Apparently, this issue occurs due to major changes  in .NET 8
and Here is the explaination.
A quick fix I found was :  adding

options.UseSecurityTokenValidators = true;

in

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()

helps. It did not work for me though ... I have decided to shift to .NET 6 for the current project. Ill update here if I find any other solution.

As per the thread on Github Updating Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect to 7.5.1 fixed it for me.

Thanks to Shaik Abid Hussain's Idea i found a solution for .Net 8:
Simply add this line:
options.UseSecurityTokenValidators = true;

Into the .AddJwtBearer(options =>{}) anonym function in the Program.cs File.
This is what it looks like for me now:
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Secret"]);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
    options.UseSecurityTokenValidators = true;
});


I've encountered with the same issue and found the fix.
According to this comment on github the Iat claim requires to be set using epoch time. In your code we can see it is set using standard string format, which worked fine in previous versions.
Change this line:
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString())

To this:
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)

But as @Shaik Abid Hussain said, adding options.UseSecurityTokenValidators = true to your .AddAuthentication() should work, because it reverts to the legacy token validation behavior from .net 6 and 7, but it didn't worked for me.

In program.cs
I am using the code below and it is working for Web API many years
//Add Json Web Token manager
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
//"JwtBearer"
x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
//"JwtBearer"
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new 
    SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)),
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false
    };
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJwtAuthenticationManager>(new 
JwtAuthenticationManager(key, expiryMinutes!, user));

