# Client side refresh strategy for refreshing Json web tokens?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json-web-token

Can someone share with me how you refresh your jsonwebtokens on the client side? I'm building a SPA with react on the front end and a restful api on the back and I don't want to make my tokens live forever. How do I implement a refresh token strategy without having to make a user login again?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration help?

Comment: @speckledcarp I was actually thinking more of the actual implementation. Like do I wrap my requests in a higher order function? What I had in mind was to do that and whenever I get the expired token just route to login page. I'm not sure if that is considered best practice though