# Refresh JWT without OAuth2

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I 'm using JWT in my spring boot application and spring security for authentication. The problem is that I can't refresh JWT token after the jwt.expiration time declared in file application.properties so the users  gets logged out after 30min . Do I need OAuth2 implementation or is there any other quick-and-dirty way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but I'll try and point you in the right direction.

Refreshing tokens is the business of an authorization server. So, your application would need to talk with one of those in order to renew the token.

I'd invite you to read up on [OAuth 2.0](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2) to understand how renewals happen. Specifically, they require a [refresh_token grant](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2#token-endpoint) from that authorization server.

Based on your description, you are likely an OAuth 2.0 Client application, in which case you'd be most interested in [Spring Security's OAuth 2.0 Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login) and [OAuth 2.0 Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client) support.

Also, I know you didn't ask this, but I'd also discourage you from seeking out "quick-and-dirty" solutions. Take the time to understand the security landscape, and it will pay you dividends later.

Comment: Also, I found that this answer, while older, is still relevant to the conversation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration