# Update Current Jwt Token Expiration on Click Event MVC .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there a way to update the current Jwt token expiration time on event?  I have a modal that warn the user their token is going to expire and they need to click a button to extend that time.  Is there a way to extend the current Jwt Token expire time without t he use of a refresh token or on event?

Comment: Seems can't, the original token can not be changed after it is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update an existing token you would've to generate a new token everytime.

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration)