# What token does an iOS app send a RESTful API for user-related requests?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, restful-authentication

I'm new to iOS and RESTful API development. I've developed a local API in Node.js that handles basic requests to and from a local MongoDB instance, and am working on user authentication via Sign in With Apple [based on this tutorial from Better Programming](https://medium.com/better-programming/sign-in-with-apple-node-js-backend-implementation-for-ios-developers-25a54b79aa68).

It's my understanding that Json Web Tokens are one of several ways the server can verify the client, in which case user-specific information is sent back in a response. My question is this: because JWTs have a short lifespan, what is sent by an iOS device to query the database for user-specific info? Do I need to have a verification method that checks to see if the JWT is expired, and if it is, issue a new one? Or is there another token that I should be using in its place that lasts longer?

The [answer to a similar Auth0 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration) implies that I should be creating a token server-side, and then providing it to the user. If this is the case, would this then be sent back and forth between the client and the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user ID provided by Apple. This is a unique identifier that is returned in the authorization credential.