# How to make JWT token expires after a predefined period of inactivity?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am using `node-jsonwebtoken` to manage my authentication workflow. Everything is okay so far, however I need to make the token expires after a predefined amount of inactivity (for e.g. 2 hours). That's mean, if the client didn't make a request using the token in the past 2 hours, for example, the token become invalid and the client need to re-authenticate.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT (JSON Web Token) automatic prolongation of expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739167/jwt-json-web-token-automatic-prolongation-of-expiration)

Comment: Why are you using JWT in this case and not just a regular server-backed session?

Comment: Yes I think I will switch to a session-based auth. It's the best option for me